# Possible bug in Python data structures

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

There appears to be an issue with Python dropping the contents of a nested dictionary. Here's the data structure of second_body:

```
body = {
    'Violations' : [
                     {'foo': 7,
                      'bar': 8,
                      'baz': 9},
                     {'tez': 2,
                      'rez': 4,
                      'sez': 6}
                   ]
}
```

Given the data structure for body. I then nest it in a final dictionary (associated with 'outdict').

```
body = second_body(body, findme)

        if g_row == 1:
            print "another check: %d " % len(body['Violations'])

        outdict[id_] = {'index': index,
                        'doc_type': doc_type,
                        'id': id_,
                        'body': body}


        if g_row == 1:
            b = outdict[1]['body']
            print "more checks: %d " % len(b['Violations'])
```

The output for the print statements are as follows:

```
another check: 8
more checks: 0
```

Somehow, between the first and second print statement, 8 values go missing. We can see that this isn't due to a function called. It appears to occur when I assign the data structure associated with outdict.

This issue is not just limited to using a dictionary. Previously, I had tried 'outlist' which appended a tuple containing four dictionaries in it. That caused the same issue.

Really not sure what's happening here. Please let me know what you think.

Using Python 2.7.8, Fedora 21, virtualenvwrapper.

Just tried to replicate the issue in a separate script. It looks like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

body = {}
body['Violations'] = []
body['Violations'].append({'foo': 7,
                           'bar': 8,
                           'baz': 9})
body['Violations'].append({'tez': 2,
                           'rez': 4,
                           'sez': 6})


print "another check: %d " % len(body['Violations'])

outdict = {}

outdict[1] = {'index': 'foo',
              'doc_type': 'doc',
              'id': 1,
              'body': body}

print "more checks: %d " % len(body['Violations'])
```

This code was not able to replicate the issue. So now I'm really doubting there's a bug associated with data structures. Is a more likely scenario that I have a syntax error somewhere that's failing but not being raised?

Here's a [link](https://gist.github.com/tbonza/8ccb828fd9cc5fc2e37f) to the exact code that's giving me the issue. The print statements are there. Let me know what you think/if you can replicate. Thanks

Comment: The code does not conform to the output. Specifically, `len(body['Violations'])` is `2`.

Comment: The length of your `body` is never 8.  It is 2 (because it contains two dictionaries).  The rest of your code doesn't make sense.  What is `outdict`?  What is `_id`?  What is `second_body`?  Please show a self-contained example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: This is true. The example as I've written it only includes two items. On the data I'm using for my machine. I have 8 items. I'll edit the question for clarity. Thanks

Comment: probability of there being a bug in your code > probability of there being a bug in the implementation of `Python`'s data structures, I know it's frustrating sometimes though, and easy to blame things other than yourself :)

Comment: @qwwqwwq in fact, I'd say `Pbug(self) >>> Pbug(Py)`

Comment: Well the easiest explanation is that `b` and `body` aren't the same dictionaries, and given you are doing `b = outdict[1]['body']`, I guess that means `id_` != `1`.

Comment: Purely guessing here, but maybe you meant to do `b = outdict[id_]['body']`?